# Apex/VF error - Need apex guidance

Tags: apex, visualforce

> Invalid type: Territory Error occurred loading controller 'LogACallVF'
> for page logacall

Users are getting this error when hitting the button that enables this VF page all of a sudden, it started a few weeks ago. I am not super apex savvy, but I have some working ability. Client says they do not use Territory and to just remove that dependency. I commented out all areas of Territory and am still receiving the invalid type error in dev console log. The log points to Line 355 for the error, but Territory isn't even on that line, here is the syntax:

```
<apex:column width="10%">
    <apex:actionSupport action="{!setPlaceID}" event="onclick" reRender="CallDetails,CallDetailsSection,CallItemSection" status="statusProcessing"> 
        <div style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">
            <input type="radio" name="SelectedAddress" value="{!a1.typ}" {!a1.isSelect}/> 
        </div>
    </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: Is the error pointing to that line in your Visualforce page, or in the controller/extension? My gut feeling is that the issue would be with the controller (or extension).

Comment: Hi Derek, the error was in the controller, but I figured it out I think. The users need to have an address or Territory populated in their user record for that PlaceID to pull in the addresses.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, never know who it can help. And you can [edit] your question to include any relevant bits you needed to understand the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be an address in the user record to populate the list of addresses to choose from on the VF page.